# Как организовать данные, что читать?

Tags: android, база-данных, файлы

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо хранить данные пользователя имя, монетки, список уровней и прочее. Как это лучше организовать? Что почитать для понимания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если много  данных связанных между собой однозначно бд, начинать читать с проектирования - основ. нормальные формы и тд ...  база для android однозначно sqlite, но пока стоит просто ее спроектировать. Если есть время (проект образовательный, а не горят сроки и надо срочно здать)  то лучше потратить недельку и нормально все спроектировать, потом это будет занимать меньше времени